# Asking the user if they would like to replay tic tac toe game after it has ended

Tags: c#, tic-tac-toe

the rest of my code works perfectly, I cant manage to figure out how to make the game replay after they say yes. I made the bool called Replay and made it true when the user types yes but the game replays at the last move made when the game ended and just asks for another move. So basically my attempt to get replay to work, doesnt work.

```
int row =0; int col =0; 
bool replay = true; 

System.Console.Write("Player 1, what is your name?: ");
String? p1 = Console.ReadLine();
System.Console.Write("Player 2, what is your name?: ");
String? p2 = Console.ReadLine();

  char[,] board = new char[3, 3];
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
       {
         for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
         {
             board[i,j]= '-' ; 
         }
        }

bool isplayer1=true;
//keep track if game has ended 
bool gameEnded = false;
while (replay)
{
    while(!gameEnded)
    { 
        DrawGameBoard(board);
        //keep track of what symbol we are using to play
        char c= ' ';

    //keep track of whose turn it is
        if (isplayer1)
        {
            c = 'X';
        }
        else 
        {
            c = 'O';
        }
        //print oout players turn

        if (isplayer1)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(p1  + "'s turn(X) ");
        }
        else 
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(p2  + "'s turn(0) ");
        }

        //check if row and col are valid
        while (!gameEnded)
        {
            //get row & col from user
            Console.Write("Enter a row (0, 1, or 2): ");
            row = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter a col (0, 1, or 2): ");
            col = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if(row < 0 || col < 0 || row > 2 || col > 2)
            {
            System.Console.WriteLine("This position is off the bounds of the board! Try again.");
            }
            //Check if the position on the board the user entered is empty (has a -) or not
            else if(board[row,col] != '-') 
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Someone has already made a move at this position! Try again.");
            }
            else
            {
                //position is valid
                break;
            }
        }
        //setting postion of board to symbol of player
        board[row,col]= c;

        bool win = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
        {
            // check rows
            if(board[i,0] == board[i,1] && board[i,1] == board[i,2] && board[i, 0] != '-')
            {
                win = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!win)
        {
            //Check each column
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
            {
                if(board[0,j] == board[1,j] && board[1,j] == board[2,j] && board[0,j] != '-') 
                {
                    win = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!win)
            {
                //Check the diagonals
                if(board[0,0] == board[1,1] && board[1,1] == board[2,2] && board[0,0] != '-') 
                {
                    win = true;
                }
                if(!win)
                {
                    if(board[2,0] == board[1,1] && board[1,1] ==  board[0,2] && board[2,0] != '-') 
                    {
                        win = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(win)
        {
            DrawGameBoard(board);
            System.Console.WriteLine("We HAVE A WINNERRR!!!!");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            isplayer1 = !isplayer1;
        }

        
        System.Console.Clear();

        //check if board full
        bool boardIsFull= true;

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                if(board[i,j] == '-') 
                {
                    boardIsFull = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!boardIsFull)
                break;
        }
    
        if(boardIsFull)
        {
            DrawGameBoard(board);
            Console.WriteLine("It's A Tie!!!!");
            break;
        }
    }
     //asking user if they'd want to replay 

    System.Console.Write("Would you like to play again :) !!? ");
    string  answer= Console.ReadLine();
    answer = answer.ToLower();
    if (answer != "yes")
        Environment.Exit(0);
    else 
    {
        System.Console.Clear();
         replay = true;
        //gameEnded= false;
    }
}

//drawing the game board 
  void DrawGameBoard(char [,] board)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
        {
            System.Console.Write(board[i,j]);

        }
            System.Console.WriteLine();
     }
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to clear the `board` of all pieces.

Comment: @VCD_WL i assumed that System.Console.Clear(); did that

Comment: Move the initialization for the board `char[,] board = new char[3, 3]; for (...)` inside the `while(replay)` loop ...

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the array **[Board]** initialization inside the while (Replay) loop.

I tried this way and it worked:

```
        bool isplayer1 = true;
        //keep track if game has ended 
        bool gameEnded = false;
        while (replay)
        {
            char[,] board = new char[3, 3];
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    board[i, j] = '-';
                }
            }

            while (!gameEnded)
            { . . . .
```